# HTML tag not working displaying as a text on browser

Tags: html, jsp, tags

I am storing text in Database with `html tags`. While displaying them the tags are not working they are displaying as text.

**DB Data:**

> `<p>send the document to:</p><p> bay area, </p><p> tampa</p>`

when i am displaying this on `jsp` it is displaying as it is with `p tags`

**Expected:**

> send the document to:
>   bay area,
>   Tampa

**Actual:**

```
<p>send the document to:</p><p> bay area, </p><p> tampa</p>
```

Comment: Show us the relevant code that renders the html.

Comment: can you show how the value stored in database table?

Comment: i am storing the text "<p>send the document to:</p><p> bay area, </p><p> tampa</p>" in the DB.

Comment: i am using a normal html tag to display the text

Comment: @user2644654: show us the code. The code matters. HTML tags don't generate text from Java objects. That's the part we're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JSTL to not escape the HTML string. For instance:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<c:out value="${yourHTMLString}" escapeXml="false"/>
```

But beware of XSS attacks.

Comment: Even simpler: drop the c:out, and simply use ${yourHTMLString}: the only thing that c:out does is to escape the HTML. If you don't want escaping, don't use c:out.